# WKWebview evaluateJavascript is not working, throws an error

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I am trying to call an existent function from a remote site in a WKWebview:

```
function addtext (text) {
 jQuery("#webviewtest").html(text);
}
```

With:

```
[self.WebView evaluateJavaScript:@"addtext(\"This is a text from app\");" completionHandler:^(id Result, NSError * error) {
    NSLog(@"Error -> %@", error);
}];
```

But this is throwing an error:

```
Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo=0x170c788c0 {NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}
```

This is so simple! I am must missing something really stupid!

Comment: Is jQuery loaded on that page?

Comment: Yes, its a fully functional website, I am just building a bridge to make a facebook login works. And the Function also works when I normally call on the browser.

Comment: Try without jQuery: `document.getElementById('webviewtest').innerHTML = text;`. Maybe `html` method fails.

Comment: Hey @Pinal, you've made me realise that was a DOM Ready problem. Look at my answer below. Cheers.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Found a solution, it was simple as I was expecting, I was adding the javascript before the view complete load the content (before the Dom Ready). So I just had to move my code to the delegate method below:

- webView:didFinishNavigation: (from [WKNavigationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKNavigationDelegate_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/WKNavigationDelegate/webView:didFinishNavigation:))

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is a solution! Obviusly but save me a lot of time thank you.

Comment: Did you implement the delegate?

Comment: Same for Android webview :D

Comment: I am having this issue in didFinishNavigation...Even with delay of 3 sec it still throws this error.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the problem was caused by the `webView:didFinishNavigation:` being called before the page content was actually loaded.  I think the website is using angularjs.

I introduced a manual delay which seemed to d the trick for me :

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    print("loaded)")
    //abtn_run(UIButton())
    self.perform(#selector(performAction), with: nil, afterDelay: 3.0)    
}
```

and did my call here:

```
func performAction() {
    //This function will perform this after delay of 3 seconds
}
```

Ideally the best solution would have a listener push an event for angularjs "page ready" but I am not sure this is possible in wkwebview.