# Error loading the following JavaScript code in a WKWebView

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I use the following JavaScript code inside a WKWebView:

```
[webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.getElementsByClassName('blog-background overlay text-center align-middle animated from-top animation-on')[0].style.display = 'NONE'" completionHandler:^(id _Nullable sha, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);

            }];
```

I get this error:

```
Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}
```

How can I solve the problem？

Comment: first try this script in a browser or jsfiddle, with your html. figure out the reason for error there.

Comment: I execute this JS code on the browser page can be hidden inside the corresponding element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WKWebview evaluateJavascript is not working, throws an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849465/wkwebview-evaluatejavascript-is-not-working-throws-an-error)

Answer (score 0):

may be because you are adding the javascript before the view complete load the content,
Write your code in below delegate method and check what happens:

```
webView:didFinishNavigation:
```

Comment: I was the operations performed in the method you said, this is hidden footView，And it delayed the execution of code 2 seconds before