# Swift: WKWebview JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type

Tags: javascript, swift, wkwebview

I'm trying to inject to my webview the below script:

```
self.webView.evaluateJavaScript(
                """
                    const OldNotify = window.Notification;
                    const newNotify = function(title,opt) {
                        var obj = {
                            title: title,
                            content: JSON.stringify(opt)
                         };

                        console.log(obj);
                        return new OldNotify(title, opt);
                    };
                    newNotify.requestPermission = OldNotify.requestPermission.bind(OldNotify);
                    Object.defineProperty(newNotify, 'permission', {
                        get: () => {
                            return OldNotify.permission;
                        }
                    });

                    window.Notification = newNotify;
            """
            ) { result, error in
                print(error)
                print(result)
            }
        }
```

But i get this error

> Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=5 "JavaScript execution returned a
>   result of an unsupported type"
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=JavaScript execution returned a
>   result of an unsupported type}

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887438/wkwebview-evaluatejavascript-returns-unsupported-type-error