# evaluatingjavascript method returning error in WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wkwebview

I am trying to submit a HTML form by javascript in WKWebView, which has input type hidden.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
NSString *submitFormJavascript = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"window.onload = function() { document.getElementById('%@').submit(); }", self.formName];
    [self.webView evaluateJavaScript: submitFormJavascript completionHandler:(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
    CPFLogError(@"javascript execution error: %@", error);
    
    [weakSelf handleError:error];
}];
```

NSError that i am getting

```
Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=5 "JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=JavaScript execution returned a result of an unsupported type
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42887438/wkwebview-evaluatejavascript-returns-unsupported-type-error

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I alredy tried this , but didn't work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The `evaluateJavaScript` method is trying to pass you result from the JS code which in case is `undefined` since you don't have explicit return. If you
`return true` from the JS code it should work without issues.

Comment: *Return statements are only valid inside functions.*